# Find max from an array that created from a form submission

Tags: php, arrays, forms, type-conversion

I've created a form and submit it as an array,

```
array(
 'name'   => 'John',
 'score1' => '50',
 'score2' => '90',
 'score3' => '75',
);
```

I want to search the maximum, from the submitted array but it always detected as string. So the result always **John**

```
<form action="" method='post'>
<?php
$dr     = array('Brian','Mike','John');
$prd    = array('score1','score2','score3');

foreach($dr AS $d){
    echo "<input name=txt[$d][dr] value='".$d."' size=3 readonly>";

    foreach($prd AS $p){
        echo "<input type=text name=txt[$d][".$p."] size=3 value=0> ";
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}

?>
<input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
    foreach($_POST['txt'] AS $v){
        $max = max($v);
        $v['max'] = $max;
        var_dump($v);
    }
}
?>
```

code:
http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/9tnu-p6yd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You provide an array of strings into `max` function and in this case this function will behave as described in documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

> Values of different types will be compared using the standard
>   comparison rules. For instance, a non-numeric string will be compared
>   to an integer as though it were 0, but multiple string values will be
>   compared alphanumerically. The actual value returned will be of the
>   original type with no conversion applied.

Replace this part of your code

```
if($_POST['submit']){
    foreach($_POST['txt'] AS $v){
        $max = max($v);
        $v['max'] = $max;
        var_dump($v);
    }
}
```

with this

```
if($_POST['submit']) {
    foreach($_POST['txt'] AS $v) {
        $scores = [];
        foreach ($v as $key => $val) {
            if (preg_match('/^score/i', $key)) {
                $scores[] = (int)$val;
            }
        }

        $max = max($scores);
        $v['max'] = $max;
        var_dump($v);
    }
}
```